# Is there a way to have your comments show up after you put them in an output file?

Tags: ruby, command-line, comments

In my Ruby file, I have multiple comments, and I am saving the output into a text file, and I was wondering if there is any way to make the comments show up in my new output file. mysql has a method that can do this which uses `--comments` in the command line. I wanted to know if Ruby has something similar to this.

For example, I would like my name and the lab name to show up in the `lab1.txt` file:

My Ruby code:

```
#My name
#lab1.rb
#description

#part 1
puts "hello world!"

#part 2
puts "hello world".length
```

Saving output into another file:

```
ruby lab1.rb > lab1.txt
```

Comment: By definition, the interpreter *ignores* comments.

Comment: No, there isn't. Don't use comments for this, use `puts`.

Answer (score 1):

### Add Lines When Standard Output is Redirected

The Ruby interpreter *ignores* comments. While you can't make the interpreter automatically print comments, you could certainly add code that would print additional information only when your code has standard output redirected (e.g. when piping output to a file). For example:

```
if ! $stdout.tty?
  puts 'Name: John Doe'
  puts 'Lab:  lab1'
  puts
end

puts 'Hello, world!'
puts 'Hello, world!'.length
```

When run without redirection, you'll only see the output from the last two lines:

```
$ ruby redirection.rb 
Hello, world!
13
```

When redirected to a file or pipe, the code within the if statement will get redirected too:

```
$ ruby redirection.rb | tee /tmp/lab1.txt
Name: John Doe
Lab:  lab1

Hello, world!
13
```